# How to make a shadow from one side with tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm trying to make a shadow from one side only, from the right side with tailwind. If I use `shadow-xl` it adds the shadow to all sides.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do these by adding [arbitrary values](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/box-shadow#arbitrary-values) to the shadow.

```
<div class="relative h-screen bg-red-50">
  <div class="absolute inset-20 h-12 w-36 rounded-lg bg-indigo-500 shadow-[rgba(0,0,15,0.5)_10px_5px_4px_0px]">shadow</div>
</div>
```

Here's a [live demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/W4TxZoJO37).
I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use the Tailwind plugin, `tailwind-extended-shadows`; it adds utilities for specifying box-shadow `x` + `y` offsets (i.e. directions), and shadow `spread`. They work alongside the built-in `shadow-{size}` (controls `blur`) and `shadow-{color}` classes, so you have full control over your shadows via utility classes.

For example:

```html
<div class="shadow-lg shadow-slate-900/20 shadow-b-2 shadow-r-[3px] -shadow-spread-2">...</div>
```

Github: https://github.com/kaelansmith/tailwind-extended-shadows

Playground: https://play.tailwindcss.com/9X5nqVNd1d

Comment: Please disclose your affiliation to the linked repository within your answer. Also, note that linking to something you made is allowed, but linking to it too much can get your answers deleted as spam. See [how to not be a spammer](/help/promotion).